# Google Spreadshirt Export more certain sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, export, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working with Google Spreadsheet and I've created a small script with Javascript to improve my workflow.
But now I'd like to export 2-3 sheets in only one .xlsx file. (I have like 7 sheets in the spreadsheet)

I found out that I can download certain sheets by adjusting the gid in the URL like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/google_spreadsheet_id/export?format=xlsx&id=google_spreadsheet_id&gid=xxx
```

But is there any way to maybe add more than one value to the gid, so the downloaded .xlsx contains 2 sheets?

```
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/google_spreadsheet_id/export?format=xlsx&id=google_spreadsheet_id&gid=xxx&gid=xyz
```

Maybe there is a workaround or a proper way to do it. I'd be happy if you could help me,
Thanks

Comment: How is the script implemented? Is it a standalone JS file or is it a bound Google Apps Script project?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer. It's a bound Google Apps Script.

Comment: To where are you trying to export?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I'm just hiding every sheet I don't want to download and move my sheets to the first position.

After that I'm renaming the whole spreadsheet, then
download the file and after that I'm renaming it back to the recent name and unhide the sheets again.